# Swift 5.1: How can I pass NULL as an argument?

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation, swift5

I am trying to set an obeserver for `CFNotificationCenter`.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543316-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver?language=objc) states:

> ### name
>
> The name of the notification to observe. If NULL, callback is called for any notification posted by object.
>   If center is a Darwin notification center, this value must not be NULL.

From what I understand `NULL` doesn't exist in Swift. So what should this argument be?

The following compiles fine, but a blank string isn't `NULL`:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(
    CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter(),
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer?.none,
    receiveNotification,
    "" as CFString,
    UnsafeRawPointer?.none,
    CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately
)
```

I've tried `CFString?`, `NSNull` and `NSNull as String` but the compiler complains.

Have I misunderstood the documentation? How do I supply a NULL value for the name paramenter?

Comment: What about `nil` ?

Comment: You can try with `nil`

Comment: @user28434 It's true. `Null` doesn't exist in Swift, but `nil` does.

Comment: @Roberto, but it's the same concept, different name.

Answer (score 5):

*Short answer:* Nullable pointers from (Objective-)C are *optional* pointers in Swift, and you can pass `nil` (aka `Optional.none`) for the name in order to be called for any notification posted by the object.

*Some background:* The C declaration of that function is

```
CF_EXPORT void CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
               const void *observer,
               CFNotificationCallback callBack, 
               CFStringRef name,
               const void *object,
               CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior suspensionBehavior);
```

where the type of the `name` parameter is a pointer, declared as

```
typedef const struct CF_BRIDGED_TYPE(NSString) __CFString * CFStringRef;
```

It is explicitly stated in the (Objective-C) documentation that `name` can be `NULL`, but apparently the function declaration has not been *audited for nullability,* and that is why the parameter is declared as an implicit unwrapped optional

```
_ name: CFString!
```

in Swift.

See [Nullability and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) in the Swift blog and [SE-0055 Make unsafe pointer nullability explicit using Optional](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0055-optional-unsafe-pointers.md) for more information about nullability and how (Objective-)C pointers are imported to Swift.

So `name: CFString!` only tells us that the Swift compiler does not know if the Objective-C parameter can be NULL or not, otherwise it behaves like a regular optional `CFString?`, and you can pass a `nil` value, which corresponds to a null pointer `NULL` in (Objective-)C.

Similarly, `const void *object` is imported to Swift as `_ object: UnsafeRawPointer!` because there is no nullability annotation, and you can pass `nil` here (what you already do in the explicit form `UnsafeRawPointer?.none`).